# Glassfish "does not have administration access" error via Ant build

Tags: java, deployment, ant, glassfish, build.xml

I'm developing an application that deploys the already done applications. At this application I'm using ant scripts to administrate Glassfish Server.

Here is my deploy and undeploy code snippets,

```
<presetdef name="asadmin">
        <java jar="${glassfish.path}/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar" fork="true" jvm="${java.home}/bin/java">
            <arg line="--port ${glassfish.admin.port}" />
        </java>
    </presetdef>

    <target name="deploywar">
        <asadmin failonerror="true" output="${out.txt}">
            <arg value="--host=${deployurl}" />
            <arg value="--passwordfile=${password.file}" />
            <arg value="deploy" />
            <arg value="--properties" />
            <arg value="compatibility=v2" />
            <arg value="--force=true" />
            <arg value="--contextroot=${war.contextroot}" />
            <arg value="${deployyolu}/${war.filename}" />
        </asadmin>
    </target>

<target name="undeploywar">
        <echo level="info">
            ${war.filename} sunucudan kaldırılıyor... 
        </echo>
        <asadmin failonerror="false" output="${out.txt}">
            <arg value="undeploy" />
            <arg value="MobilHis" />
        </asadmin>
        <echo level="info">
            Proje sunucudan kaldırıldı. 
        </echo>
    </target>
```

When I call this code snippet from java I got this error via server.log .

```
User [] from host localhost does not have administration access
```

I'm using Java JDK 1.6.0_27 and Glassfish Server 3.1.2

Also I deployed this application to another Glassfish Server and it worked just fine. Now what should I do?

-I double checked the username and password and they were correct.

-My passwordfile.txt formatted like `"AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password"`

-I also can login to glassfish server via localhost:4848 interface.

Comment: What OS is this deployment occurring on?  Do you have proper permissions [running deploy script as glassfish user or root, or ..]?

Comment: It should have been platform independent, but deploy process occurs at Linux. I'm calling this script as Ant Task from java, I guess as admin user.